# Advice on which statistical tests to perform in this scenario

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I am trying to perform a couple of statistical tests to determine significance from categorical variables (e.g., treatment, station)

The experiment is microcosms with freshwater amended 2 different types of oil to measure degradation. 3 different stations with 3 different salinities and temperatures were set up and in triplicate bottles. Subsampling for degradation data happened every 2 days and the experiment ran 14 days total. Having the hydrocarbon data, we see slight decrease in oil concentration but I am wondering how to determine if this decrease over time is significant? and if decreases between each time point is significant?

Based on previous literature I think I should be using ANOVA or 2 way t-test? however those tests do not seem to take time into consideration?

Are there other tests you think would be helpful?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to find out whether oil concentration varies as a function of oil type, salinity type, and temperature? Are the 3 latter categorical variables and oil concentration a continuous variable?

Comment: I want to find out if the decrease in oil concentration is significant between time points (e.g., day 0 and day 14, day 0 and day 7), and also if the degradation is a function of salinity temperature and temperature. Oil type is a categorical variable (2 different oil types). I believe temperature and salinity are discrete variables? I.E. 5C, 10C, 20C and 1PSU, 10PSU, 30PSU. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, you did say you wanted the effect of time, I read carelessly. 

I think some kind of regression would work better than ANOVA or a t-test, but based on the info you gave I suppose an ANOVA with time, oil type, salinity and temperature and their interactions as factorial predictors would work, as long as you have enough observations as there will be a lot of comparisons. Can the stations be seen as equivalent apart from the manipulated salinity and temperature?

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I will try both linear regression and ANOVA. I would say the stations are quite separate as an MDS ordinations shows their ecologies are very different.

Comment: OK, in that case you need to control for station variance - maybe consider a multilevel model with the random intercept of station included (unless salinity and temp are perfectly confounded with station, in which case it may be difficult to enter all three into the model).

Comment: Hi thank you. Okay so for a 'multilevel model' are you referring to ANOVA or regression tests? Do you have a suggestion of a program or R package to do this?

Comment: I meant a multilevel regression, for instance in R you can use lme4 or nlme packages for this, and in SPSS the Linear Mixed model function. But I think more info about the exact structure of the data would be needed to see whether that would be appropriate and how it would be best to specify.